# Pass UDF result to :tabe in VIM

Tags: vim, user-defined-functions

I've written a small function in my .vimrc to translate a string to a file path.

```
function FindPath(param)
    " some logic here
    return goodPath
endfunction
```

This much is working.  What I want to do is bind a key to open a new tab with the result of FindPath and the current cWORD.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to pass the result to :tabe.  Either it treats it literally or I'm getting syntax errors all over the place.

```
nnoremap <leader>c :tabe FindClass(<cWORD>)
```

Is basically what I want in a pseudo-code sense, I just cannot get the syntax right to save my life and this is somewhat difficult to search for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use tabs so much, I guess you were stucked at the `exec` and `expand()` part. You could try this line:

```
:exec 'tabe '.FindPath(expand("<cWORD>"))
```

If this works for you, you could create the map in your way like:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :exec 'tabe '.FindPath(expand("<cWORD>"))<cr>
```

Comment: My hero, thank you!  I knew of expand and exec but couldn't come up with the right order of operations.  Thank you again!